# FreeMarker: left-hand operand: Expected a hash, but this has evaluated to a number (wrapper: f.t.SimpleNumber)

Tags: java, list, freemarker, xssf

I am using `freemarker 2.3.28` and trying to assign a value to a variable but I get the **error** in the title

```
<#list 0..row.getLastCellNum()-1 as cell>
        <#assign cellValue = cell.getStringCellValue()>
        <#assign cellAddress = cell.getAddress().toString()>
        <#if someCondition>                                         
            <td style='background-color:orange'>${cellValue}</td>
        <#else>
            <td>${cellValue}</td>
        </#if>
</#list>
```

The error occurs at the second and third lines. The variable `row` is a `XSSFRow` object which is passed in inside a `List` that I am iterating through with an outer `list (<#list rows as row>)` which is not shown here.

Why is this happening and how can I resolve this?

Thank you.

Comment: It's not related to your question, but note that instead of `cell.getAddress()` and such, you can write `cell.address`. Cleaner and more convenient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to me that `cell` is never being assigned to an actual cell object. Your `<#list 0..row.getLastCellNum()-1 as cell>` line is just going to assign the loop counter number to the cell variable.  If you changed it to this you'd be ok?:

```
<#list 0..row.getLastCellNum()-1 as idx>
    <#assign cell = cell.getCell(idx)>
    <#assign cellValue = cell.getStringCellValue()>
    <#assign cellAddress = cell.getAddress().toString()>
    <#if someCondition>                                         
        <td style='background-color:orange'>${cellValue}</td>
    <#else>
        <td>${cellValue}</td>
    </#if>
</#list>
```

I didn't see anything in the POI javadoc that exposed getting all the cells from the row otherwise that would be simpler.

Comment: You're absolutely right @B-Wieg, I tried to print out the value of cell and its only the loop counter. I guess I confused it with for:each loop in java :)